# I cannot run this code to print distance between two points. I am just a beginner

Tags: c++, constructor

I wrote the code given below to print distance between two points but it throws a lot of errors. As much as I know, the errors lie in "void formula(distance o1, distance o2)"and main. But I couldn't find exact errors as I am just a beginner. Please guide me.

```
class distance
{
     int a, b;
public:
    int c, d;

    friend void formula(distance, distance);

    distance(int a1, int b1)
    {
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
    }
 };

void formula(distance o1, distance o2)
{
    c = o2.a - o1.a;
    d = o2.b - o1.b;
    cout<<"The distance is "<<sqrt((c*c)+(d*d))<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    distance c1(1, 2), c2(3, 4);
    formula(c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I spot one unmatched bracket. In general, extract a [mcve] before asking. You could have found this mistake. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Focus on the first error and include the exact error message in your question. (Copy-paste it as text; don't paraphrase.)

Answer (score 1):

In the function formula c and d are not defined.
this function would know about them if you write

```
o1.c = ...
o1.d = ...
```

Comment: `c` and `d` should be removed from the class